# Docker port mapping: 3-way handshake although nothing is listening

Tags: tcp, docker

I am launching a Docker container with a port mapping:

`docker run -d -p 1234:1234 busybox sleep 10000`

Expected behavior is "Connection refused", i.e. `SYN, RST+ACK`.
What I see is "Connection closed by foreign host", i.e. `SYN, SYN+ACK, ACK, FIN+ACK, FIN+ACK`.

I use telnet like this: `telnet localhost 1234`
and tcpdump like this: `sudo tcpdump -i lo -w xxx.pcap -v -n tcp port 1234`

Why is Docker behaving like this?

Comment: FWIW, we hit this issue and raised this [bug report](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/18189).  Apparently the solution is to use `--userland-proxy=false`, but we haven't tried it yet.

Comment: I just tried it. It works as expected now. So your comment answers my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Oliver Charlesworth commented the behavior I experience is caused by Docker's userland proxy. The userland proxy can be disabled with `--userland-proxy=false` in `/etc/default/docker`.